# template typedef C++11

Tags: templates, c++11, typedef, using

I was trying to use C++11's "using =" syntax to typedef a templated comparison function. I then define a templated-function and want to assign it to comparisonFunc of type "ComparisonFunction".

```
  template<typename ValueType> using ComparisonFunction = bool (*)
                 (ValueType const & val1, ValueType const & val2);

    template<typename ValueType>
    bool equalFunction(ValueType const & val1, ValueType const & val2) {
        return val1==val2;
    }

    template<typename ValueType>
    ComparisonFunction<ValueType> comparisonFunc = equalFunction<ValueType>;   //Error is here

    int main()
    {

    }
```

The first few lines work, but declaring equalFunc (without even giving a value to it) gives the error

```
error: template declaration of 'bool (* equalFunc)(const ValueType&, const ValueType&)
```

All I found on this error was related to C++03 where no "using =" syntax exists.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You ask about type definitions, but what you're having problems with is a function definition or a function pointer definition, not a type definition.

Answer (score 3):

Your declaration

```
template<typename ValueType>
ComparisonFunction<ValueType> comparisonFunc = equalFunction<ValueType>;
```

is a variable template, since the declaration is for the variable `comparisonFunc`, not a type or function.  C++14 allows variable templates, but there is no such thing in C++11.

Comment: C++14 will allow variable templates... -> "Will"?

Comment: Oh, I missed that it's been officially approved!

Comment: Template variable?! Can you point me in the standard / draft? I can imagine static constexpr template variable, but normal non-static?

Comment: @firda See paragraph 14/1 "Templates [temp]" of the current standard: "A declaration introduced by a template declaration of a variable is a *variable template*".

Answer (score 0):

Since you require a different function pointer for each instantiation of `equalFunction`, you can make `ComparisonFunction` a functor. As you said, template aliases don't exist in C++03 so your final code is:

```
template<typename ValueType>
bool equalFunction(ValueType const & val1, ValueType const & val2) {
    return val1==val2;
}

template <typename ValueType>
struct ComparisonFunction
{
    bool operator()(ValueType const & val1, ValueType const & val2)
    {
        return equalFunction(val1, val2);
    }
};
```

Comment: My goal is to create a type ComparisonFunction so that I can assign any kind of comparison function. For example, in the beginning, it should be a equalFunction, and later on in the code, this same variable should refer to a LessThanFunction